# What is the use of the "msapplication-TileImage" meta tag?

Tags: html, meta-tags, meta

I have come across the following code:

```
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#113228">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="icon-tile.png">
```

Could someone please explain what those meta tags are used for?
I can't find any documentation about those tags.

Comment: Did you do any research? I've never heard of them but found this with a google search https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn455106(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @MartinSmith Thank you. Though, am I missing something? The documentation you provided doesn't mention anything about the "msapplication-TileImage" meta tag

Comment: @MartinSmith you have manners?

Answer (score 16):

It let you pin website icon on Windows 8 Modern UI

Comment: Do you have a link to the official documentation?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/dn255024(v=vs.85)#msapplication-tilecolor

Comment: also exists in windows 11

Answer (score 0):

On a website, the "msapplication-TileImage" meta tag is set to specify a background image for the website tile on the Start screen. It is use Internet Explorer 10 on a computer that is running Windows 8.